# cannot retrieve stack trace from logcat on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, stack-trace, logcat, runtimeexception

When I'm debugging an app today, I constantly get `W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cf2390)` from the logcat when the app crashes, without any further info. The logcat filter is the app, but even if I filter in all info., there's still no runtimeException shown with the stack trace. I'm using a real device. So I wonder how I can get more useful information from logcat? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding a try catch(Exception ex) block and in the catch block type  ex.printStackTrace

Comment: Maybe help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735161/android-studio-missing-exception-stacktrace-in-logcat

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue right now.  My solution was to run adb logcat from the command line.  There was the stack trace loud and clear (I forgot to add my activity to the manifest)!  I'm not sure why it's not showing up in Android Studio (I'm actually using IntelliJ...)