# Android Studio missing exception stacktrace in Logcat

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, logcat

For some time, Android Studio doesn't show me stacktrace when developed application crashes. All I can see is following line:

```
06-09 16:12:36.875  26037-26037/com.a.b W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4206c700)
```

This drives me crazy because I cannot see, where application really crashed (and what exception occurs). I'm using AS 1.3 Preview 2. At first I though there is problem with dependencies, but now I'm using just these and problem still occurs:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
}
```

Problem is probably based on fact that application doesn't crash, but only freeze.

Thanks for every suggestion.

Comment: Do you have the android tool window, where you are viewing logcat, set to "Show Only Selected Application", and the process you have selected in the other drop down to the right of the device is not the process you'd like to view?

Comment: I've tried both, "No Filter" and "Show Only Selected Application", but problem still occurs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to remove all dependencies in your build.gradle file. IMHO, the bug will be in **play-services-analytics**. Google Analytics tracks exception. Try to remove `tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true)` in your code.

Comment: I have no idea why, but commenting out line as you've suggested solved the problem.

Comment: Life saver! Thank you so much!
Commenting the line above does work!
Not sure why it only happens after switching to Android Studio. Thank you @skywall for posting the problem and for solving.

Comment: This works because Google Analytics sets itself as the defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler for the main thread and intercepts the stack trace to send to Analytics without logging to logcat.

Comment: `FirebaseAnalytics` from `firebase-core` has the same problem. Call `setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)` to see stack traces, or, even better, set it to `!BuildConfig.DEBUG` so you can see stack traces in debug builds while tracking exceptions in release builds.

Answer (score 6):

The same thing started happening to me after I updated my Android Studio. After hours of frustration, I found out that clicking on the Filter dropdown menu on the right side of the logcat screen and clicking on **No Filters**, *even if it's already set to No Filters*, fixes the issue. I don't know if it will work in your case but you might as well give it a try if you haven't already.

Comment: Set dropdown value to "No Filter" doesn't solve the problem. Logcat now produces a lot of unrelated (in my opinion) logging information, but still no stacktrace.

Comment: @skywall, clicking on the small trash can in the upper left corner in the logcat window deleted old logs and showed newer logs to me.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on [Radim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801092/54829), logcat doesn't show exceptions that are handled by the [setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) for the main thread.

You probably use an analytics library that registers itself as the default `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

Note that, this doesn't only apply to uncaught exceptions, but also to exceptions that you log with `android.util.Log`. Code like this should log an exception, but will only show the "Failed" message:

```java
try {
  something();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Failed", e);
}
```

Logcat will show this, with no stack trace, regardless of whether you use `Log.w`, `Log.e`, etc.

```
V/MyApp: Failed
```

Radim called out `play-services-analytics` as a common culprit, but Google's new analytics library is `firebase-core`; it has the same problem. I fixed it by disabling analytics collection on debug builds.

I changed this line:

```java
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

to this:

```java
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG);
```

Thus, when I run debug builds in development, Firebase analytics doesn't handle exceptions, and I can see them in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that Android studio was showing logs from a restarted version of the app rather than the one that just died.

To see the stacktrace from the app version that has died, there is a drop down on the right of the logical window which allowed me select the logs from the dead app:

[image]

This then showed the correct stracktrace.