# Logcat uncaught Exception details not appearing on actual device but emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, uncaught-exception

```
    W/dalvikvm﹕threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41823da0)
    I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 07-03 14:54:48.967
    I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 
       ---> Exception details missing here
```

I have recently noticed that when the app I'm developing crashes no exception details are shown at logcat if running on an actual device (tested on Galaxy S3-Android and 4.3 and Galaxy S5-Androdid 4.4) but If I reproduce the crash on an android emulator a full exception stack trace is available.

I'm using Android Studio 1.3, Platform-tools 22, Build-tools 22.0.1

Have you encountered a similar issue? Did you managed to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable USB Debugging on your device?

Comment: @JorgeCasariego of course, they are enabled and I can see my own logs, only Exceptions are missing

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30801092/2091181

Comment: I'll post like an answer :D Did you use Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **Google Analytics** remove all dependencies in your build.gradle file because Google Analytics track all exceptions.

Remove **tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true)** in your code.

Original answer was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801092/2091181)

Comment: I need analytics, so I just commented out tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true)