# Difficulty to debug using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Recently I just switch from Eclipse to Android Studio.

I am having issue to debug with Android Studio, specifically, most of the time, the app doesn't crash when any error happens (eg. exception). Instead, the app just hang in the emulator or device for long time and prompt a dialog:

**"The app isn't responding. Do you want to close it?"**

When I check the logcat, **no Exception** found like in Eclipse which can help me identify the coding issue quickly.

One example is, when I use "TextInputLayout" without importing the **Android Support Design Library**. When testing with emulator, it just hang there without showing any precise error in **Logcat**.

I wonder what settings can I modify so that I can debug quickly and efficiently like in Eclipse ?

**Update:**
Another simple example: if I I forgot to add new <activity> tag in Android Manifest for my newly created Activity class, the app simply hang there with "not responding" instead of crash and throwing error in Logcat like before in Eclipse.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have an active breakpoint which is causing the app to freeze? Because you are not stepping over?

Comment: It will not give error because there is no exception generated for not responding try on android 5

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution. If you are using Google Analytics, commenting the line below, then the app will crash and display Exception at Logcat instead of freezing.

```
//tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true)
```

Check the reference below:
[Android Studio missing exception stacktrace in Logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735161/android-studio-missing-exception-stacktrace-in-logcat)